# Fix Server Time on NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, time, server

Running Node JS and ExpressJS, my server time seems to be 5 hours ahead. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Closing this since it's not a reproducible problem. The issue is likely that the *local time* of your *remotely running server* is different than the *local time* of your *client*. Consider using the `getUTC` and `setUTC` prefixed methods on your [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of us face this problem when dealing with time issues, such as producing charts based on times and dates, so you are  not alone. No matter what time your server is on, it will not match the timezone of everyone who uses the Node.js program, unless this is a private creation. Some suggestions:

1. You did not mention what type of server. First, you need to decide what Timezone (tz) you will be using for your Node.js program (for sanity purposes if nothing else). If you have a model that will be accessed from anywhere in the world, then people expect certain things to be in their local time, while others can be in UTC.
2. Your programs (modules) need to be aware of when they are using UTC or not. For instance in a DB where you have a timestamp, you need to know what time is being used for that timestamp, so calculations based on TZ can be correct afterwards.
3. Now the headache. For a serious management of TZ and formats, you should use [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment). However, and I say this after painful experience, though [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) is great, take time to understand it. I would not suggest just diving in, but take the time to understand just how to manipulate the TZ correctly for a UTC especially for your own needs. TZ in moment goes from the easy to a fairly elaborate scheme. [Read up on it here](http://momentjs.com/docs/).
4. There are some other datetime modules which are excellent, (just go to [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com) and search for date time) and moment has some other plugins (like [twix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twix)), so the field is covered.
5. Finally, be real careful with date variable declaration and avoid scoping and hoisting with date and time variables. In datetime these especially, have unseen consequences.

Hope some of the above helps.